# Access .Onion links using programs other than Tor Browser? (VLC, etc)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, vidalia

How would I be able to access a tor hidden service without the use of TBB? For example, an RTMP server hosted through Tor. In this scenario, I'd like to access the RTMP server using VLC, but VLC would not be able to use the .onion url.

Is there any way in which I'd be able to use such .onion urls outside of TBB? Possibly accessing .onion sites by using tor system-wide somehow?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy.

1. Goto Tools -> Preferences and set `show setting` to **all**.
2. Goto Input/Codecs -> Socks Proxy.
3. Type in your proxy address: `127.0.0.1:9050`

After that, you should be able to access any .onion links using VLC Player.

Comment: This seems to clear the main issue of actually reading the url, however I'm still faced with a connection problem in VLC's logs: "http error: cannot connect to [...].onion:80"
Though, in TBB I can still connect to the site and fetch files as well.

Any idea what could be causing this in VLC?

Comment: @chatbottest , is there an option to change DNS server in VLC?

Comment: I don't think so, or at least, I haven't found one.

Comment: Scuse me here guys, if you want to use your tor server on localhost to point an app to it's fine but there is a need for support sock5 within the app, you can still use system wide proxy and all your connections are going to be redirected through tor yet this might not be a good idea concerning discretion because if you ever reach Google, facebook, or whatever giant, they'll log that e.g. you open chrome while torifying but the browser is connected to your account... bad.

Comment: About your os , if you are not using linux then you won't find much help out there, windows is mainly designed to be sold to rich victims who believe that the box is more important than the content. So many things are already hiden in term of knowledge within the hardware itself and back to electric principle to afford working on a platform whose code is kept secret and sold out, putting pressure even on whole governments to maintain some feeling of hegemony. Cheers

Comment: Yeah I agree with you about Linux, however I'm tied to using Windows 7 for this project. 

I'm not actually worried about discretion or anonymity, as this is all just for testing purpose. That said, in what ways could I Torify my entire connection on Windows 7?